# Template using directive specialization

Tags: c++, templates, alias, partial, specialization

While template specialization is allowed, one can't specialize a template using directive.
What are some tricks to achieve it anyway ?

e.g :

---

this is ok :

```
template <class A>
class MyTemplate { ... };

template <>
class MyTemplate<int> { ... };
```

---

this isn't :

```
template <class A>
using Alias = SomeClass<A>;

template <>
using Alias<int> = MyBigIntClass;
```

EDIT:

The goal is to use `Alias<int>` in the client code, and have it be `MyBigIntClass` under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the trick (use template specialization) :

```
template <class A>
struct Helper{              //default case
    using t = SomeClass<A>; //use void or omit this line to disable default case
};

template <class A>
using Alias = typename Helper<A>::t;

template <>
struct Helper<int>{
    using t = MyBigIntClass; //whatever you need
};

int main()
{
    Alias<int> a = 0; //It's MyBigIntClass under the hood
}
```

Comment: @Casey the OP and Answerer is the same.

Comment: @40two I know - That's why I'm surprised the details of the answer don't match the details of the question.

Comment: @Casey thanks because I though I was tripping. I don't see any relationship with the question here.